# How do I wait a certain amount of time before continuing in PHP?

Tags: php

So this is kind of two questions...

First off, when a user logs out, I want to redirect them back to the login page. I do this by using `header('login_form.php');`, however, prior to doing such, I try to print out the text "You have successfully logged out. You are now being redirected to the login form.". I do this using echo and echoing out the text, however, the header runs so quickly that I'm almost immediately transferred back to the login form, without getting a chance to read the message. So, how can I delay a little bit, and let the message display for just 5 seconds or so prior to redirecting the user with the header?

My second question is, what's the best way to simply display "incorrect login" above the login form? So, when I browse to the login form and enter an incorrect user/password, instead of going to "login.php" and then redirecting back to login_form.php, it simply determines whether the login was a success or not, and if not simply displays "Incorrect Login" above the input fields, as opposed to having to redirect back to login_form (which also doesn't notify the user that the login was incorrect).

Comment: Why do you need the login splash screen at all? Just redirect the user straight to where they want to go if the login is successful

Comment: In the future, please ask each invididual question in a separate Question.

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ: Under some circumstances I think it could be useful. If you're just saying "You're not logged in" then it's fairly useless but if it contains a nice welcome message like "Welcome back, user! We're glad to see you again." then it's completely fine. It's site preference, similar to how it's store preference whether there's a greeter at the door when you walk in.

Comment: IMO messages like that are a waste of time and bandwidth (not just mine, yours too - that's why sites like google, facebook, or even SO don't have them). I know you *aren't* glad to see me again - you are a script, incapable of feeling emotion. Just take me to where I want to go. But to each his own.

Comment: Also, if you are so compelled to include a welcome message, you can embed that into the page somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Return a simple HTML page with a meta refresh tag pointing to the desired location in the `<head>`.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=login_form.php">
```

This will refresh (redirect) the page after 5 seconds to the given URL. I'd also consider adding a direct `<a>` link for the impatient.

```
<p>
   You are logged out. You will be redirected to the login page in 5 seconds. 
   Click <a href="login_form.php">here</a> if you're impatient.
</p>
```

I personally find 5 seconds too long. Make it 3.

---

As to your second question, just let the form submit to self and redisplay the very same form with dynamically inlined error messages next to the input fields. Only redirect if the login has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

1. Doing this in php alone would be difficult, or perhaps even impossible depending on the circumstances.  Instead, take them to `logout.php`, or whatever page displays "You have been logged out," and simply add a `meta` `refresh` header, as in:
   `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=login_form.php">`
   This will redirect them to `login_form` in 5 seconds.  This is a popular technique, but I can't guarantee it will work in all circumstances either.  However, as the other answer suggests, you can include a link to redirect directly.
2. This can be done with javascript (you can perform the validation with ajax and display an appropriate error message/let them log in as needed).  If javascript is not an option or if you also need to handle users who don't have it, when `login.php` rejects the authentication, set a `_SESSION` parameter such as `_SESSION[login_fail_message] = true`.  On `login_form.php`, check if this value is true.  If it is, display your "Incorrect login" message.  Clear this value on login attempt (or ideally if they leave the page).

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, know that changing the location header will have an immediate effect.  Some sites allow the login form to display the message that the user has successfully logged out.

For the second part, have javascript do the validation first and display any errors client-side.  If it passes the javascript, have the server do the server-side validation from the POST and return the login form again, but this time with the error areas marked.  A login success should redirect them instead as normal.